# How to create the following figure from csv with 2 columns in R language

Tags: r, histogram

I have this csv-file without column name:

```
0.21,2200
0.22,2161
0.23,2384
0.24,2059
0.25,1510
0.26,1343
0.27,1681
0.28,1501
0.29,938
0.30,686
0.31,598
0.32,399
0.33,385
```

And want to plot the similar histogram(with the value in first column as x-axis and the second as y-axis) as shown in this figure.

[image: Histogram]

How can I achieve it? Thank you for your reply.

```
df<-read.csv(file="c-all-prop.csv",head=F,sep=",")
require(ggplot2)
qplot(x=df[,1],weight=df[,2],geom="histogram",xlab="Proportions of GD",ylab="No. of strains",binwidth = 1)
```

This code created somehow a strange result in the following figure. I wonder why.

[image]

Comment: You can't. Two reasons - you have less info than the histogram has and your values are different

Comment: Thanks.I mean a similar figure.

Comment: Is your problem with how to read the data into R? Or how to draw a histogram?  There are answers to both questions here on SO.  Let us know what you have tried, and be more specific about your problem.

Comment: e.g.: d<-read.csv(file="c-all-prop.csv",head=F,sep=",")
x <- d[,c1]
          I see. d[,1] instead of d[,c1]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation with ggplot2. I have put your data in a csv read it and shared its structure via dput. This should work without columnnames too.

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27, 
                             0.28, 0.29, 0.3, 0.31, 0.32, 0.33), V2 = c(2200L, 2161L, 2384L, 
                                                                        2059L, 1510L, 1343L, 1681L, 1501L, 938L, 686L, 598L, 399L, 385L
                             )), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                             -13L))

require(ggplot2)
qplot(data=df,x=df[,1],weight=df[,2],geom="histogram",xlab="Proportions to whatever",ylab="No. of strains whatever")
```

[image]

Experiment with binwidth option of qplot to get the desired spacing in histogram.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me what's wrong with my following code. `df<-read.csv(file="c-all-prop.csv",head=F,sep=",")
require(ggplot2)
qplot(x=df[,1],weight=df[,2],geom="histogram",xlab="Proportions of GD",ylab="No. of strains",binwidth = 1 ) `.

Comment: You have not given data = df

Comment: Not, it did work. But the final plot seems to be very strange. I show you the figure in my question.

Comment: What's strange about it?

Comment: I reedited my question, pls see the fig. The maximal value in y-axis should be 2161. But in the plot, it is far beyond 2161. Also the x-axis is not corret.

Comment: Can't tell without seeing the data. There are other options in qplot that let you limit the axes values like xlim, ylim etc.. But this should not happen.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking how to plot a pre-binned dataset in R, where for example you have a CSV file of buckets and counts instead of all of the values of an underlying distribution.  The [HistogramTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HistogramTools/) R package on CRAN provides the `PreBinnedHistogram` function which accepts a vector of buckets and a vector of counts and returns a normal R histogram object you can plot or manipulate.

Your plot doesn't match the description and the data, but the following plot I think faithfully represents what you describe better than the plot included in the question:

```
require(HistogramTools)
counts<-c(2200,2161,2384,2059,1510,1343,1681,1501,938,686,598,399,385)
breaks<-(21:34)/100
plot(PreBinnedHistogram(breaks,counts))
```

[image]